# How is an efi application being set as the bootloader through code?

Tags: operating-system, boot, bootloader, uefi

By following this [tutorial](https://wiki.osdev.org/UEFI#Boot_mechanism), I am able to create a simple efi application that prints hello world when **executed from an uefi shell**. However, I was wondering how does one creates bootable EFI image. I tried to use bcfg command in the shell and added my efi binary as one of the booting sequence. However, is there anyway to do it without the need of going into the shell?

> However, if you are actually building your own firmware, you can also
>   look at creating a bootable EFI image and set your default boot option
>   to this binary. This is most useful if you are including the binary as
>   a part of your ROM, but it might be a little involved to set up the
>   filesystem so that it is seen as a normal boot option.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22641605/running-an-efi-application-automatically-on-boot?answertab=oldest#tab-top), Nicholas Embry gave a good answer but I was unable to find any resource to explore further into the topic that he mentioned. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bcfg`, just like `efibootmgr` in Linux, ultimately use the `GetVariable()` and `SetVariable()` runtime services (also available during boottime) to modify the system boot configuration.

The UEFI Shell, implementing the `bcfg` command, is itself a UEFI application. Since its source is publicly available, you can have a look at the implementation of the `bcfg` command - particularly the [BcfgAdd()](https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/blob/2a6ede28fd8efd3051794e1f2727a692d2725fe9/ShellPkg/Library/UefiShellBcfgCommandLib/UefiShellBcfgCommandLib.c#L525) function.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to unixsmurf's answer, I figured that it is in the specification that UEFI will automatically look for a file name/located at EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi. When making a UEFI application that is intended to be automatically loaded by the machine when booting, simply place the application at the specified path. Combining with what unixsmurf mentioned, I can make the computer load any UEFI application automatically at boot time.

Comment: Yes, but do note that on many systems this will bypass boot entries set in the `Boot####`/`BootOrder` variables. This is referred to as the 'removable media path', and generally used for things like operating system installers. Also worth noting is that the path is architecture-specific.